# NSManagedObjectContext not seeing changes to attribute of entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am pretty new to Core Data.

My data model has a a `User` entity which has an attribute, `fullName` which is fetched from a server. I am displaying a list of all `Users` in a table view using `NSFetchedResultsController`. As all the `Users` get their `fullName` attribute updated, I expect the MOC to send a did change notification. However, it is not doing that. Hence, my FRC isn't getting updated either.

I have cleaned and built, modified my data model and built and even deleted `User.h/m` and regenerated it. I am still not able to figure out what the problem is though. And the `fullName` is actually getting updated, I can manually reload the table view and see the changes. What is my problem?

Code:

Setting `fullName`:

```
- (BOOL)methodName:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    self.fullName = data[@"fullName"];
    self.imageData = data[@"image"];
}
```

Table view:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.frc.sections[section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
User *user = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:user.imageData];
cell.textLabel.text = user.fullName;
}
```

Setting up FRC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if (!self.model) self.model = [XPModel sharedInstance];
[self.model addDelegate:self];

if (!self.frc) {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([User class])];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES]];
    request.fetchBatchSize = 10;

    self.frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.model.moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.frc.delegate = self;
}

NSError *error;
[self.frc performFetch:&error];

NSAssert(!error, error.localizedDescription);  
}
```

FRC delegate methods:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];  //  Only this is called, and only at the beginning
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];  //  Never called
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}
```

Setting up the model:

```
- (void)coreDataSetup
{
NSError *error;

NSURL *storeURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].lastObject URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"userdb.sqlite"];;
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];

NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
NSAssert([storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error], error.localizedDescription)

self.moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
self.moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`? If so, can you show it?

Comment: ... and set the FRC delegate?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko Yes, I copied it from Apple's sample code so no changes there. It is not being called.

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: We might need to see some code.  Specifically how you set `fullName` and the table view controller that displays the `Users`.

Comment: are you updating in the background (what is your context architecture)?

Comment: I have a single MOC on the main thread. I'm pretty new to Core Data, so trying to keep it simple right now.

Comment: Where do you call `methodName:`?  Is it from the main thread?

Comment: All of my application runs on the main thread, as of now.

Comment: Even when fetching `fullName` from the server as you indicated in your question?

Comment: Yes, the class fetching data from the server runs on the main thread. I checked all suspects with `[NSThread isMainThread]`.

Comment: could you show us your `model.moc` method?

Comment: @DanShelly That's a simple getter. I put up the code where I set the MOC up instead.

Comment: is it possible that `coreDataSetup` is getting called twice? did you look at Apple's data stack implementation?

Comment: `coreDataSetup` is only called once. Yes, I looked at Apple's implementation. Though I copied mine off some blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of this delegate callback:

> This method may be invoked many times during an update event (for example, if you are importing data on a background thread and adding them to the context in a batch). You should consider carefully whether you want to update the table view on receipt of each message.

I recommend that you do not rely on this mechanism. It would be better to disable the delegate during the import. Simply save and reload your table once you are finished (or periodically according to some batch quantity).

I did not see you save anywhere - you should also do this periodically when importing large amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks… that's what I ended up doing. I reload the table view after receiving the last user data packet from the server and meanwhile display an activity indicator over the table view. My app checks if there are any changes to the context every 30 seconds and saves if there are. It also saves every 3 minutes while backgrounding.

Comment: Maybe it would be even better to use the `...didSaveNotication`. Whenever there is a batch saved, you can update the UI.